# not sure the properly way to call an entity

Tags: entities, 9

Hi sorry for the question but im new and im starting to undertand abou entities but is still hard for me. IM not sure about how to call the entities.

Here i didnt have a problem tu get the number.

```
$price= \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->get('unit_price')->getValue()[0]['number'];
```

But here i dont undertand why i could not take a percentage y try to many combinations. Maybe some one can show me the proper way to write this.

```
  $product_tax= \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->load($id)->get('adjustments')[0][0]->get('value')->getvalue()['percentage'];
```

Debug:

```
^ Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem {#3230 ▼    
  #values: array:16 [▼    
    "order_item_id" => array:1 [▶]    
    "type" => array:1 [▶]    
    "uuid" => array:1 [▶]    
    "order_id" => array:1 [▶]    
    "purchased_entity" => array:1 [▶]    
    "title" => array:1 [▶]    
    "quantity" => array:1 [▶]    
    "unit_price" => array:1 [▼    
      "x-default" => array:2 [▼   
        "number" => "151.250000"    
        "currency_code" => "EUR"   
      ]    
    ]
    "overridden_unit_price" => array:1 [▶]
    "total_price" => array:1 [▶]
    "uses_legacy_adjustments" => array:1 [▶]
    "data" => array:1 [▶]
    "created" => array:1 [▶]
    "changed" => array:1 [▶]
    "locked" => array:1 [▶]
    "adjustments" => array:1 [▼
      "x-default" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:1 [▼
          "value" => Drupal\commerce_order\Adjustment {#3231 ▼
            #type: "tax"
            #label: "IVA Incluido"
            #amount: Drupal\commerce_price\Price {#3233 ▶}
            #percentage: "0.21"
            #sourceId: "europeo|es|standard"
            #included: true
            #locked: false
          }
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The *unit_price* field has two properties: *number* and *currency_code*. This means you could use both the following lines.

```php
$price = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->get('unit_price')->getValue()[0]['number'];
$currency = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->get('unit_price')->getValue()[0]['currency_code'];
```

The *adjustments* field has only the dafault property, *value*. It means you can only use the following code.

```php
$value = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->get('unit_price')->getValue();
```

`$value` should be an array containing the *#percentage* index. That value should be available in `$value[0]['#percentage']`. Debugging as you did, you could see what exactly `$value` contains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer i already try, but nothing. i also try tochange unit_price for adjustements like this:
$value = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->get('adjustments')->getValue()[0];
$adjustments = $value['#percentage'];

Comment: You need to check what `$value` contains.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I understand how to get the values from arrays. This is the solution:

```
$percentage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order_item')->load($id)->getAdjustments()[0]->getPercentage();
```